# Typewriter-effect using Code Block as the Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to showcase a specific code segment on my website using the Typewriter effect. I not only want it to be displayed but also "typed" out when the page loads.I havent found a solution, hopefully you can help me. Here is the code I currently have:

```
'use client';
import { Code, HStack, Heading, VStack } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import Typewriter from "typewriter-effect";


export default function AnimatedCodeBlock() {
    
    return (
        <>
            <Code children={
                <Typewriter options={{
                   delay:1,
                   autoStart: true,
                   strings:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod"
                  }} />
            }></Code>
        </>
    );
}
//Code I Would like to be displayed.
/*

using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your `Code` block in a `pre`.

Have a try with:

```
const code = `
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
`;


<pre>
  <code>
    <Typewriter
      options={{
        delay:1,
        autoStart: true,
        strings: code
       }}
     />
  </code>
</pre>
```